# VBA Code, but need to keep rows with no data

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to delete rows that do not meet a certain criteria.  The code is working, however, I can't figure out how to keep the blank rows separating the data.  Below is the code I'm using.  It works well for deleting what I want it to, however, it also is deleting the blank lines in between.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim i As Long
For i = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If (Range("E" & i).Value > -5 And Range("E" & i).Value < 5) Then
         Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    If (Range("D" & i).Value > -500 And Range("D" & i).Value < 500) Then
    Range("D" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    End If
    Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be enough to check for blank spaces and if a cell is blank, do not delete that row. Like this

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim i As Long
For i = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If (Range("E" & i).Value > -5 And Range("E" & i).Value < 5 and Range("E" & i) <> "") Then
         Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        If (Range("D" & i).Value > -500 And Range("D" & i).Value < 500 and Range("D" & i) <> "") Then
            Range("D" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked beautifully!!!  Thank you.  It's been a long day, and that last part was giving me a headache.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I understand long days and headaches myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding another And statement should do the trick for example you can use <> to say Does Not Equal.

```
If (Range("E" & i).Value > -5 And Range("E" & i).Value < 5) And Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then
```

Comment: It's a while since I used VBA... why is `Range("E" & i).Value <> ""` better than `NOT ISEMPTY(Range("E" & i).value)` ?

Comment: @DarrenH - If a cell is set to an empty string (e.g. simply type a `'` into a cell, or use a formula such as `=""`) then `Range("E" & i).Value <> ""` will be True but, because the cell is not empty, `ISEMPTY(Range("E" & i))` will be False.

Comment: In this specific case though, any string (even a ZLS) would fail the `value < 5` check and so would never even reach the empty check